# Full Screen Video On A Mobile Device in Landscape

Tags: html, css, video, mobile, landscape

Below is the code that I'm using for my website. Everything is working as it should, but I can't get the video I've set to play full screen when in landscape on my smartphone (iPhone 12).

Does anyone know how I can set the video so that it displays to each edge of the screen when my phone is in landscape?

[Landscape on Mobile Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp8Bx.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 ;" charset="utf-8">    
    
<body>

<title>MORIKOBOSHI - 公式ウェブサイト・Official Website</title>

<div class="video-container">
<video src="Home_Page.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline style="z-index: 100px; overflow: hidden; object-fit: contain;"></video></div>
 
<div class="relative">
<p style="text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: hidden; color: transparent; opacity: .45;"><a href="Home.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: black; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 darkgray,-1px 1px 0 darkgray,1px -1px 0 darkgray,-1px -1px 0 darkgray;">盛りこぼし</a>
</div>

<div class="absolute">
<p style="text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: hidden; color: transparent; opacity: .8;"><a href="Home_English.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: black; opacity: .8; text-shadow:.5px .5px 0 #FFFFFF,-.5px .5px 0 #FFFFFF,.5px -.5px 0 #FFFFFF,-.5px -.5px 0 #FFFFFF;">MORIKOBOSHI</a>
</div>
    
<div class="home_page">   
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: hidden;"><a href="Website_Home_Page.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: white; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000;"><b>日本語</b></a> |  <a href="Website_Home_Page_English.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: white; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000;"><b>English</b></a></p></div>   
    
<style>
    
    .relative{font-size: 25px;}

    .absolute{font-size: 13px;}
    
@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px){
    
    .relative{font-size: 11px;}
    }

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px){
    
    .absolute{font-size: 6px;}
    }
    
.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container video {
  /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;

  /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* Center the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) and (orientation: landscape){  

.video {image-fit: fill;}}
    
.relative {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -13px;
   
}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px){
    
    .relative{position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -30px;}
    }

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 28px;
    top: 28px;}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px){
    
    .absolute{position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -15px;}
    }
    
video {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;

}
    
p {          
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none; color: white; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000;
  font-size: 400%;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;}

.home_page {
     position: fixed;
     top: 520px;
     left: 410px;
    }
    
@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px){  

.home_page {position: fixed;
     top: 470px;
     left: -08px;}
}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) and (orientation: landscape){  
    
.home_page {
     position: fixed;
     top: 180px;
     left: 160px;
     font-size: 20px;
    }

}
    
</style>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code for video remove the min-height and min-width instead give height and width of 100% as I have done check the code. I hope it solves your issue.

```html
 .video-container video {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue. Changing the position of the container also caused the buttons on the page to disappear.

Comment: I tested your code and video is working fine on full screen on landscape mode. Can you share a screenshot to better understand your problem.

Comment: I think I found your issue , I have edited my answer you can check it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: I added a screenshot. As you can see there are white lines on either side of the video. I'd like to get rid of them. The code above doesn't solve the issue, rather makes it worse as it doesn't display full screen on a PC.

Comment: I added the CSS code in the answer below. the issue was most likely in object-fill property. Check if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for this code. Unfortunately, I'm still seeing those white bars appear on the sides of the video in landscape. Any other suggestions for how I might be able to get rid of them?

Comment: Well its working now correctly on my device. I don't understand why it has issues on your devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have customized the CSS and fixed some object-fill issues, Copy the CSS code . Now it works fine in my pc and responsive mobile screens. Check if it works for you also.

```css
  .relative {
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      .absolute {
        font-size: 13px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) {
        .relative {
          font-size: 11px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) {
        .absolute {
          font-size: 6px;
        }
      }

      .video-container {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .video-container video {
        /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */

        /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        /* Center the video */
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        .video {
          object-fit: cover;
        }
      }

      .relative {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: -13px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) {
        .relative {
          position: absolute;
          top: -15px;
          left: -30px;
        }
      }

      .absolute {
        position: absolute;
        left: 28px;
        top: 28px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) {
        .absolute {
          position: absolute;
          top: 4px;
          left: -15px;
        }
      }

      video {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        object-fit: cover;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        object-fit: cover !important;
      }

      p {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000,
          -1px -1px 0 #000;
        font-size: 400%;
        margin: 50px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 3;
      }

      .home_page {
        position: fixed;
        top: 520px;
        left: 410px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) {
        .home_page {
          position: fixed;
          top: 470px;
          left: -08px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        .home_page {
          position: fixed;
          top: 180px;
          left: 160px;
          font-size: 20px;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this code. Unfortunately, I'm still seeing those white bars appear on the sides of the video in landscape. Any other suggestions for how I might be able to get rid of them?